# Installing Link Grammar Python binding on OSX: "Could not link test program to Python"

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, binding

I am trying to install the Link Grammar Python binding on OSX 10.10.3 Yosemite. I run the following command directly from the unpacked downloaded directory (link-grammar-5.3.7):

```
./configure --enable-python-bindings
```

but I get this error:

```
  Could not link test program to Python. Maybe the main Python library has been
  installed in some non-standard library path. If so, pass it to configure,
  via the LDFLAGS environment variable.
  Example: ./configure LDFLAGS="-L/usr/non-standard-path/python/lib"
  ============================================================================
   ERROR!
   You probably have to install the development version of the Python package
  for your distribution.  The exact name of this package varies among them.
  ============================================================================
```

As a result I tried to figure out where my python library path is by running `locate pymath.h`:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pymath.h
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/pymath.h
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pymath.h
/anaconda/envs/py27/include/python2.7/pymath.h
/anaconda/include/python3.5m/pymath.h
/anaconda/pkgs/python-2.7.11-0/include/python2.7/pymath.h
/anaconda/pkgs/python-3.5.1-0/include/python3.5m/pymath.h
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pymath.h
```

For context, `which python` returns `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python`.

Then I tried running ./configure with each of these paths, for example:

```
./configure --enable-python-bindings LDFLAGS="-L/anaconda/pkgs/python-2.7.11-0/include/python2.7
```

Each time, I either got the same error as above, or `C compiler cannot create executables`.

I tried to follow the instruction "install the development version of the Python package", but learned that ["I don't need python-devel"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32578106/how-to-install-python-devel-in-mac-os) and tried running `brew uninstall python; brew install python` due to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33843313/cant-find-a-way-to-install-python-dev-on-mac-os-x).

`./configure` without `--enable-python-bindings` runs fine, so the problem is with python.

Does anyone have any advice about how to create these python bindings? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In LDFLAGS, you have to use the location of the **libpython** library.
The location of the include files, if needed, can be specified with:

```
CPPFLAGS="-I/path/of/include-directory"
```

You may find some hints about what to do next, in issue [#298](https://github.com/opencog/link-grammar/issues/298) at the link-grammar repository on GitHub.

If you still have problems, consider to open an issue there.